# How to point a pointlight in a specific direction?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use a `PointLight` as a `SpotLight` but my camera is looking along the `-z` direction whilst the pointlight points to `( 0, 0, 0 )`

Hoe can I point it to say `( 0, 0, -100 )`?

Comment: A pointlight emits light equally in all directions from its position. What do you mean by "pointlight points to 0,0,0"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a light shining to a specified point, use the *SpotLight*.

```
// White spotlight shining to the point [0, 0, 0] along Z axis.
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotLight.target.set(0, 0, 0); 
spotLight.position.set(0, 0, 100);
spotLight.angle = 1; // angle of light dispersion (radians)
scene.add(spotLight);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with mr. Falk , right now your pointlight at 0,0,0 . 
you should position your pointlight at 0,0,-100

Comment: This is no answer, you should have upvoted the existing answer if you agree with it.

Comment: Mr. Wilt ,If you see my answer closely ,than you found i also suggest some thing new regarding to question . I suggest to change position of pointlight from 0,0,0 to 0,0,-100 .

Comment: @Wilt are you the founder of stackoverflow or what..?? Why do we have to follow your suggestions..?? As i can see you edited the question with worthless changes.. So if you don't have answers keep yourself away from technical questions.

Comment: Dear @Ritesh, A `PointLight` as you can read [here in the three.js documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight) points in **all directions**, which means that it **cannot** point anywhere. So changing direction (what the question asked for) on a `PointLight` does not make any sense. I just improved some styling in the question to make it more readable. I did not answer the question myself, because @Tomas answered it correctly. Posting twice the same answer is against stackoverflow rules, I upvoted his answer instead.

Comment: @Ritesh By the way where is *Neeraj* in this question/answer and by no means you have to follow my suggestions. Do whatever makes you happy...